# How to specify which scripts to run when there's multiple JavaScript in the same folder?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have multiple java scripts that are unrelated to each other but uses the same content of configuration file and dependency. Currently, I created separate folder/projects for each script(each is called `index.js`)and run each of them through `yarn start`. I would like to put all these scripts into one folder, what `yarn` command should I use to run a specific script? Can they use the same `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just specify a script by each of them in the `package.json` ex,

```
"start": "file1",
"start-local": "file2"
```